# Getting error: write() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
gd = open("gamedata.py" , "rb+")

gd.write(CharHealth = 100)

gd.close
```

I'm receiving the error message: write() takes no keyword arguments, and I cannot figure out why. My best interpretation is that the code is trying to interpret `(CharHealth = 100)` as a keyword argument instead of writing it to gamedata.py.

I want to write `(CharHealth = 100)` (as a line of code) along with other code to gamedata.py

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write text, then *pass in a `bytes` object*, not Python syntax:

```
gd.write(b'CharHealth = 100')
```

You need to use `b'..'` `bytes` literals because you opened the file in binary mode.

The fact that Python can later read the file and *interpret the contents an Python* doesn't change the fact you are writing strings now.

Note that `gd.close` does nothing; you are referencing the `close` method without actually calling it. Better to use the open file object as a context manager instead, and have Python auto-close it for you:

```
with open("gamedata.py" , "rb+") as gd:
    gd.write(b'CharHealth = 100')
```

Python source code is Unicode text, not bytes, really, no need to open the file in binary mode, nor do you need to read back what you have just written. Use `'w'` as the mode and use strings:

```
with open("gamedata.py" , "w") as gd:
    gd.write('CharHealth = 100')
```

Comment: gd.write('CharHealth = 100') returns the error message: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Yes, that's why he told you to write it as bytes.