# write() takes no keyword arquments in Python

Tags: python-3.7

I get this error:

```
TypeError: write() takes no argument
```

I tried to write as str(k), but nothing helps

```
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","w")
for k,v in sorted(course_catalog.items()):
    f.write(k,end='')
    f.write(':',v)
f.close()
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

I expected the keys and the values of my list. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","w")
for k,v in sorted(course_catalog.items()):
    f.write(k,'')//why use "end="
    f.write(':',v)
f.close()
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

There is no need to use `"end=''"` in a function, just `f.write(k,'')`
Or, if you are trying to actually write `end=''`, make sure to put it in quotes:

```
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","w")
for k,v in sorted(course_catalog.items()):
    f.write(k, "end=''")//Make sure to put it in quotes
    f.write(':',v)
f.close()
f = open("lab8_674046492_answers.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to using `end =` in function.

See this...
[Getting error: write() takes no keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167724/getting-error-write-takes-no-keyword-arguments)